# Piecewise functions

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, tkinter, piecewise

I'm fairly new to python and would like to know why I can't graph a piecewise function like below, and why the error message is popping up?

```
def get_data(self, frame):
    self.ydata =np.piecewise(self.xdata, [self.xdata<.2, self.xdata>=.2][ np.sin((self.frequency) * self.xdata +
                                                                frame), np.sin((5*self.frequency) * self.xdata + frame)])
```

It says my error is

```
  line 72, in get_data
    frame), np.sin((5*self.frequency) * self.xdata + frame)])
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple
```

I guess my question can also be what would I bind the piecewise function to? This is an animation and I'm doing this piecewise for a variable for my second go at it, but I don't know what i should put as 'x' if I'm wanting  x<.2 because my x values are in an arange set-up.

Comment: Please include the exact error message.

Comment: @Bryan Oakley ```line 72, in get_data
    frame), np.sin((5*self.frequency) * self.xdata + frame)])
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple```

Comment: @VanillaceIce Please [edit] to put the error message in the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what self is in the question.  My code below works as a function but can be changed to a method if required.

Your error message is caused by there not being a comma between the condition list and the function list.

```
def get_data(self, frame):        
    self.ydata =np.piecewise(self.xdata, [self.xdata<.2, self.xdata>=.2]  # Must be a comma here
        [ np.sin((self.frequency) * self.xdata + frame), 
          np.sin((5*self.frequency) * self.xdata + frame) ] )
```

Another problem is that the function lists must be functions, not the result of functions.

```
import numpy as np    

def get_data(xdata, frame):
    def f_lt(x):
        return np.sin( frequency * x + frame)

    def f_ge(x):                                                                                              
        return np.sin( 5*frequency * x + frame)  

    return np.piecewise(xdata, [xdata<.2, xdata>=.2], [ f_lt, f_ge ])

frequency = 1.0

xdata = np.arange(1,26)/25
get_data(xdata, 0.1) 
# array([ 0.13954311,  0.17902957,  0.21822962,  0.25708055,  0.89120736,
#         0.96355819,  0.99749499,  0.99166481,  0.94630009,  0.86320937,
#         0.74570521,  0.59847214,  0.42737988,  0.23924933,  0.04158066,
#        -0.15774569, -0.35078323, -0.52983614, -0.68776616, -0.81827711,
#        -0.91616594, -0.97753012, -0.99992326, -0.98245261, -0.92581468])
```

I'm not sure what you're trying to do so I can't test the result but perhaps this helps.

**Edit:** Response to a comment.

`get_data(x, frame)` can be called as often as required.

It may be better to expand the params list to make it more flexible.  It really depends on what you're trying to do.

```
def get_data(xdata, frame, frequency, step_point=0.2 ):
    def f_lt(x):
        return np.sin( frequency * x + frame)

    def f_ge(x):                                                                                              
        return np.sin( 5*frequency * x + frame)  

    return np.piecewise(xdata, 
                       [xdata<step_point, xdata>=step_point],
                       [ f_lt, f_ge ])
```

None of the parameters in the function are now hardcoded.  They can all be set each time the function is called.

```
for frame in range(100):
    frame = frame / 100
    y = get_data(xdata, frame, frequency, 0.2)
    do_plot(xdata, y)
```

Does this answer your comment?

Comment: @Tis Chris, thank you! I think I'm going to use this as a basis for the change of the variable rather the entire equation, but this really helped

Comment: @ Tis Chis, sorry one more question- is there any way to assign a single name to the equation overall?

Comment: @VanillaceIce.  I'm not sure what you mean.  The functions can be named with any valid python name.  You could give the list of functions a variable name, `name = [ f_lt, f_ge ]'.

Comment: @Tis Chris, I probably misworded it, but I was wondering if I could refer to it all under one name for the rest of the code. I f I wanted to call back the final result to plot it, or would I have to say both individually?